Unable to use a MOSFET to connect two capacitors in series
I am trying to design a circuit such that I can connect two capacitors in series by applying a gate voltage to a N-type (specifically IRF530N) MOSFET. I am getting results I do not understand. When I use two batteries instead of two capacitors (with IC = 2 V), I get an expected voltage drop across the 100 Ω resistor. This is not the case with the capacitors, as shown in the figures.
Any help, and explanations would be very much appreciated.



V1 is referenced to ground, M1 is not - what do you expect its gate-source voltage to be? Did you set initial voltages for the capacitors? Otherwise, why would they differ from zero?

The transistor has no DC bias. The source and drain need a path for DC current but the capacitors block DC.
You could add some resistors across the capacitors to bias the transistor. The resistor values would need to be low enough to provide enough bias current for the transistor but high enough to not affect whatever the capacitors are doing in your circuit. It’s a bit of a trade-off between bias and leakage.
Update:
Based on your comment that you have set the initial charge on the caps to 2 V I took another look at it. It looks like what is happening is the capacitors are quickly discharging at the beginning of the waveform. You may wonder why 1 Farad caps would discharge so fast, it's because they are not 1 Farad caps, they are 1 femtoFarad caps. In LTspice an f for the units stands for femto,  which is \$10^{-15}\$, or 0.001 pF.
If you set your sim command to .tran 0 1p 0 you'll see that the voltage starts at 4 V and decays quite quickly.
If you want 1 Farad simply put the number 1 without a unit designator.

Hi GodJihyo, thanks for the reply. The capacitors are the sources, they are charged with 2V each.

@Skeeter4life see my update.
